# How to compile DEC UNIX v4.0 application source code in Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, unix, compilation

I have the source code of a very old software that was designed to be compiled on a **Digital Unix V.40** operating system. Now I want to compile and run it on Ubuntu 20.04 operating system. The software was compiled in the digital Unix operating system with the CC compiler, which is now obsolete and is not supported by GCC. Based on the errors I received, what gcc switches should I use to fix this problem?

```
cc  -O2 -Olimit 2000 -g -migrate -assume -Zp1 noaligned_objects ...
cc: error: 2000: No such file or directory
cc: error: noaligned_objects: No such file or directory
cc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-migrate’
cc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-assume’
cc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Zp1’
```

Comment: Change the command line options to be legal for "gcc". Try `gcc -O2 -c file.c -o file.o`.

Comment: those compile flags are for mipspro or something like that.  you'll have to transalate them to gcc or whatever you are using equivalents

Comment: Also, porting code from DEC UNIX to Linux may require a whole lot more than just compiling it with `gcc`, depending on how portably the source code was written...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start with compiling it with no system-specific flags (i.e. by using `gcc` possibly with `-I`, `-L`, and `-l` flags and nothing else). If the program in question is portable enough, then it will be a matter of getting all dependencies available for it.

Once you are able to *build* it, see if it runs as expected (ignore performance). If it doesn't, that would be a good time to look at the flags you used on DEC to see if it requires any special treatment when building. This is where you either make the program portable or try to get the equivalent behavior using `gcc` on the target architecture of your choice.

Finally, once the program builds and runs, that would be a good time to see if you want to use any optimization flags (hint: you don't have to. If it runs fine, leave it the way it is).

Comment: I think that it is important to enable all warnings with `-Wall` and debugging info with `-g`; some old codes are no more standard compliant (the C standard has evolved). So improve the source code till you get no warnings. Once you debugged and tested your application, consider adding optimization like `-O2` (performance could increase significantly, e.g. by 20%).

Comment: I'd be tempted to forego the warnings until the code is more or less compiling — no missing headers, etc.  Then think about turning on the warnings.  But getting the warnings will be a good idea.

Comment: @Alexander L. Belikoff > i try but i get new problem "unknown type name ‘uchar_t’" & "unknown type name ‘uint’"

Comment: Try including `sys/types.h` (you can force this by passing `-include sys/types.h` Command line flag to `gcc`)

Comment: removed "unknown type name ‘uint" but this error stay :"unknown type name ‘uchar_t’"